# Change server name in OpenVPN file with sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have the following file:

```
    proto udp
    resolv-retry infinite
    nobind

    #Single line of those bellow, I've added multiple for variations of it 
    remote fi.server.com 50505
    remote us-cityone.server.com 5050
    remote uk-citytwo.server.com 50500
    remote us-citythree.server.com  56546
    remote sweden.server.com 6546546
    rest of config file..
```

Let me be more clear, this is a OpenVPN conf file. I want to replace only that line that starts with `remote servername 5555` - **server name** a different one.

I've added multiple `remote servername 5555` lines just for an example, because they all represent variations that I might occur.

I want to match middle column only, `fi.server.com` , `us-newyorkcity.server.com` etc and replace it using `sed` with different name.

Why pattern like this, doesn't work?

```
sed -i.bak 's/\w+(-|\.)\.?\w+\.?\.com/g' filename
```

I've tried this one as well..

```
sed -i.bak 's/\w+(-|\.)\.?\w+\.?\.\w+/g' filename
```

Further note, from the example `us-newyorkcity.server.com` only `server.com` part is a static one. Rest is changed.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you post the expected output example ?  You said `only server.com part is a static one. Rest is changed.` How do you want it changed ?

Comment: Please improve the title.

Comment: @phk Title is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a variable `NEWNAME` with the name you want to insert, you should be able to use the following:

```
sed -i.bak "s|^\(remote \)\([^ ]*\)\([ ]*[0-9]*\)|\1$NEWNAME\3|" filename
```